# Netsuite Suitescript - tranid - To Be Generated

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Full Script below.

Even after saving the newly created invoice the document number says 'to be generated' when I try to retrieve it. The record is definitely saved because I can see the invoices.

I have tried loading it using variations of this code:

```
var recordId = context.objRecord.id;

            var newRecord = record.load({
                type: record.Type.INVOICE,
                id: recordId,
                isDynamic: true,
            });
```

But this results in the error

*Cannot read property "id" from undefined*

I appreciate there are other posts on this, but none of the suggested solutions work and the Oracle documentation is so limited in this regard, all of the examples they give include a hardcoded tranid.

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NScriptType ScheduledScript
*/

define(['N/runtime', 'N/record', 'N/search'], function(runtime, record, search) {
    return {
        execute: function(context) {
          var objRecord = record.create({
          type: record.Type.INVOICE, 
          isDynamic: true,
          defaultValues: {
          entity: 3413
    }
});

var mySearch = search.load({
    id: 'customsearch2318'
    });
    
    var mySearchItemFilter = search.createFilter({
    name: 'item',
    operator: search.Operator.ISNOTEMPTY,
    summary: search.Summary.GROUP
});
    var mySearchItemFilter = search.createFilter({
    name: 'quantity',
    operator: search.Operator.ISNOTEMPTY,
    summary: search.Summary.SUM
});
    var mySearchItemFilter = search.createFilter({
    name: 'cost',
    operator: search.Operator.ISNOTEMPTY,
    summary: search.Summary.MAX
});


        mySearch.run().each(function(result) {
            var item = result.getValue({
                name: 'item',
                summary: search.Summary.GROUP
            });
            var quantity = result.getValue({
                name: 'quantity',
                summary: search.Summary.SUM
            });
            var cost = result.getValue({
                name: 'custcol_location_sales_cost',
                summary: search.Summary.MAX
            });

             log.debug({
                    title: 'items', 
                    details: item + " " + quantity + " " + cost
                });
                
        
        objRecord.selectNewLine({
           sublistId: 'item'
        });
            objRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'item',
            value: item
        });
        
            objRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'quantity',
            value: quantity
        });
        
            objRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'rate',
            value: 1
        }); 
        

            objRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'custcol_location_sales_cost',
            value: cost
        });
        
        objRecord.commitLine({
                sublistId: 'item'
            }); 
                
            return true;
        });

        objRecord.setValue({
            fieldId: 'location',
            value: 1
        });

            objRecord.save()

            
var docNum = objRecord.getValue ({
    fieldId: 'tranid'
})

            
                log.debug({
                    title: 'New Invoice', 
                    details: 'Record creation progress' + docNum
                });

        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing stuff, as I can see, you are using context in a scheduled script as if you were in a user event.
You were right in the beginning.
When you save your invoice, it returns an id and keeps the old state without reference.
You need to save the invoice id in a variable and retrieve the invoice by reloading it or with search.lookupfield (Better because it consumes less ressources)

Example:

```
let saved_inv = objRecord.save();
let saved_inv_tranid = record.load({type: "invoice", id: saved_inv}).getValue ({fieldId: 'tranid'})
```

or

```
let saved_inv = objRecord.save();
let saved_inv_tranid = search.lookupFields({
    type: search.Type.INVOICE,
    id: saved_inv,
    columns: ['tranid']
}).tranid
```

Edit: lookupfield return an object, thanks @Krypton

Comment: Thank you my friend. I’ve signed off for now and am kicking back with a beer, but I will fire up my laptop over the weekend and try. Your logic is sound and I am sure it will work. Thank you for the answer, I really do appreciate you taking the time. I will keep you posted.

Comment: One small nitpick: `search.lookupFields()` doesn't return an array; it returns an object.  So you don't need `search.lookupFields(...)[0].tranid` - rather, it should be `search.lookupFields(...).tranid`